# How to get the Jacobian matrix for this differential equation?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> y_1'(t) = -k_1y_1 + k_2y_2   \\
> y_2'(t) = k_1y_1 - k_3y_2^2
> \end{cases}
> $$

let's put $(y_1',y_2')$ as the function part in jacobian matrix, and put $(y_1,y_2)$ as the self change variable part in jacobian matrix, the partial diffrential of $y_1'$ with respect to $y_1$ should be $-k_1$? but there is some relationship between $y_1$ and $y_2$, can we just throw the $k_2y_2$ part?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
y_1'(t) = -k_1~y_1 + k_2~y_2\\
y_2'(t) = k_1~y_1 - k_3~y_2^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

$$\text{Jacobian },~J = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial y_1'}{\partial y_1} & \dfrac{\partial y_1'}{\partial y_2}\\\dfrac{\partial y_2'}{\partial y_1} & \dfrac{\partial y_2'}{\partial y_2}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-k_1 & k_2\\ k_1 & -2k_3y_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need to know why the J[1,1] is -k1? Since when you change y1, y2 is also changed, shouldn't the partial differential be with respect to the only changed variable?

Comment: Show the definition of Jacobian